# React show component based on variable value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension

Learning React & chrome extensions the hard way, so my `this.url` has one of 2 values:

`null` or `www.sample.com`

I'm getting the url value from an async call using `chrome.storage.local.get(...)` so once I get the response from the storage I set the value to this.url and want to use such value to display a component using a ternary operator like so:

```
export default React.createClass({

  url: '',

  componentDidMount: function(){
    this.observeResource();
  },


  observeResource(){
    var self = this
    function getValue(callback){
      chrome.storage.local.get('xxxx', callback);     
    }
    getValue(function (url) { 
      this.url = url.xxxx;
      return this.url;
    });
  },

  /* RENDER */
  render: function(){
    return (
      <div className="app">
        <AppHeader />
          {this.url != null ?
          <VideoFoundOverlay />
        : null}

        {this.url == null ?
          <VideoNotFoundOverlay />
        : null }             
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

I can not get the value of `this.url` outside of the `observeResource` function. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The `this` inside the following call points to `window` rather than the component itself, since the callback is invocated as a function, the `window` is actually the "owner" of the function.

   ```
   getValue(function (url) { 
     this.url = url.newswireStoryUrl;
     return this.url;
   });
   ```

   To avoid this error, you could use `self.url` instead, since you have explicitly assign `this` to `self`. Or you could use [`Arrow Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Lexical_this) instead of `function(...)`.
2. To render the component, you should declare `url` as a state, because only state changes will cause the `render` function to be called.

   ```
   export default React.createClass({
     getInitialState: function() {
       return { url: '' };
     },
     componentDidMount: function(){
       this.observeResource();
     },
     observeResource(){
       var self = this;
       function getValue(callback){
         chrome.storage.local.get('newswireStoryUrl', callback);     
       }
       getValue(function (url) { 
         self.setState({ url: url.newswireStoryUrl });
         return self.state.url;
       });
     },
     /* RENDER */
     render: function(){
       return (
         <div className="app">
           <AppHeader />
             {this.state.url !== null ?
             <VideoFoundOverlay />
           : null}

           {this.state.url === null ?
             <VideoNotFoundOverlay />
           : null }             
         </div>
       );
     }
   });
   ```

Comment: this vs self => to be or not to be...always getting confused. Great explanation thx!

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [**this.setState()**](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.state = {
    url: ''
  }
}

componentDidMount() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.setState({ url: 'www.sample.com' })
  }, 1000)
}

render() {
  return <div>this.state.url</div>
}
```

Look at working example in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/SergeyBaranyuk/Lg6m8m6t/3/)

Comment: Sorry but still not clear how to assign the storage response and use it to display component, can you elaborate pls.

Comment: I've created JSFiddle. I need to know Is it helpful for you? https://jsfiddle.net/SergeyBaranyuk/Lg6m8m6t/2/

Comment: checking now. will let you know

Answer (score -2):

I would go by and do it like this:

```
export default React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function(){
        return {
            url: null
        }
    },

    componentDidMount: function(){
        this.observeResource();
    },


    observeResource(){
        var self = this
        function getValue(callback){
            chrome.storage.local.get('newswireStoryUrl', callback);
        }
        getValue(function (url) {
            //here you are seting the state of the react component using the 'self' object
            self.setState({url: url.newswireStoryUrl})

            //not sure if the 'return this.url' is needed here.
            //here the 'this' object is not refering to the react component but
            //the window object.
            return this.url;
        });
    },

    videoNotFound: function(){
        return (
            <div className="app">
                <AppHeader />
                <VideoNotFoundOverlay />
            </div
        )
    },

    /* RENDER */
    render: function(){
        if(this.state.url == null){
            return this.videoNotFound()
        }

        return (
            <div className="app">
                <AppHeader />
                <VideoFoundOverlay />
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```